# Alert the contents of the bar variable using the foo variable

Tags: javascript

Alert the contents of the *bar* variable, using the value in the *foo* variable

```
var foo = "bar";
var bar = "foobar";
```

in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

avoid eval! use instead brackets notation: window[foo]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
<script>
var foo = "bar";
var bar= "truc";
alert(eval(foo));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = "bar";
var bar = "foobar";
alert(eval(foo));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stevevaubell/HRTAX/

Answer (score 1):

If `bar` is global, then you can do access the its contents with

```
window[foo]
```

If it is local you'd have to use [`eval` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) or better, make it a property of a local object:

```
var someObj = {}
someObj.bar = "foobar";

alert(someObj[foo]);
```

Comment: How is window diff from eval or what is it?

Comment: @weblearner: `eval` is evaluating arbitrary JavaScript code. `window` is an object and you just access a property of it. They are two totally different things.

Answer (score 0):

If the `foo` and `bar` is not global, you can not access `bar` by `window[foo]`, instead `this` will always work.

```
var foo = "bar";
var bar = "foobar";
alert(this[foo]);
```